# Mysql date_created to current time zone

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

hi i have a mysql sql

```
$select ->from('unique_link as ul',
                    array('ul.unique_url','date_created'+,'(select COUNT(*) from click where click.url_id = ul.url_id) as unique_visitors'))
                ->joinInner('campaign as cm','ul.campaign_id = cm.campaign_id' .....
```

the date_created is currently in UTC i need to add +08.00 hrs..how can i do so in query !! badly need help on this.Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: yes how i can do it in above query..?

Comment: What data type is `date_created`?  INT, TIMESTAMP, DATETIME?

Answer (score 0):

If you add Date in MySQL, I Think, date added is servor time date, you want to read the Mysql Documentation for DateTime [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

But, in your tags, we can see you use the Zend FrameWork, you can read [this article](http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.locale.date.datesandtimes.html) ( in the zend framework official Website) for learn how to use Zend_locale. With Zend Locale, you can create/edit date and time with the locale date of user...

After create date/time with 8h added, you can add the date in your MySQL request for saving here on your database.